# I can't get Googe API to access my php arrays with latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I query the latitud and longitud from my database and stored these values in php using  arrays. Since I have to use javaScript to use the Google API I pass the arrays to javaScript arrays but when I tried  to make an addMarker function to pass the latitude and longitude, the marker is not being displayed.
If there is a problem using the Json way to pass an php array i would ,ike to know too.

`var lat =     "[{"latitude":"-73.44282246117739"},{"latitude":"-73.43353928556874"},{"latitude":"-74.01881776353744"},{"latitude":"-74.0188170929852"}]"; var lng =     "[{"longitude":"40.73354088144067"},{"longitude":"40.76232657450102"},{"longitude":"40.64831233555079"},{"longitude":"40.648312844313715"}]"; var name =      "[{"name":"Saint Kilian"},{"name":"Island Harvest"},{"name":"Long Island Cares Inc"},{"name":"City Harvest"}]"; var urls =      "[{"url":"https:\/\/stkilian.com\/"},{"url":"https:\/\/www.islandharvest.org\/"},{"url":"https:\/\/www.licares.org\/"},{"url":"http:\/\/www.cityharvest.org\/"}]"; var map;`

`

```
    This is the javascript Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        margin-left: 50%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var lat =      <?php echo json_encode($latitudes); ?>;
      var lng =     <?php echo json_encode($longitudes); ?>;
      var name =      <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;
      var urls =      <?php echo json_encode($urls); ?>;
      var map;
      var latLong = {};
      

      lat.forEach((element, index) => {
        latLong[element] = lng[index];
        });

      function initMap() {

          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 9,
          center: {lat: 40.75296142342573 , lng: -73.42661893505269},
        });
        
     addMarker(latLong);
        
          
          function  addMarker(){
             
            console.log(myLatlng);
            var markerMap= new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {myLatlng[0]},
            map,
          });
            
         const popUp = "Hi";
          //Info Windows
          const detailWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: popUp,
               ariaLabel: "Food Bank",
          });
          
          markerMap.addListener("click", ()=>{
              detailWindow.open({
              anchor: markerMap,
              map,
              
          });
          });
          }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api  /js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

For some reason only works with a static latitude and longitude.

Comment: Please avoid including your API key to your post especially if it is unrestricted. you should delete your API key and generate a new one and make sure that you restrict them as per [API Security Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#separate-apikey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might helps.

`Remember json_encode() parameter must be array or object.`

Use single quotes or double quotes to enclose json data in javascript.

```js
var lat = `<?php echo json_encode($latitudes); ?>`;
var lng =`<?php echo json_encode($longitudes); ?>`;
var name =`<?php echo json_encode($names); ?>`;
var urls =`<?php echo json_encode($urls); ?>`;
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it, I was using associative fetch in PHP, and my arrays became objects instead of arrays. after I fetched by rows and used parseFloat when accessing the data in JavaScript, I was able to get the markers to show.

```
enter $sql1= "SELECT latitude
        FROM locations";       
$result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1);
$lat =  array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)>0){
    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_row($result1)){
    $lat[] = $row;
    }
}here

enter addMarker(parseFloat(lng[0]),parseFloat(lat[0]));here
```

Comment: If you post code, post properly indented, readable and usable code. If **your** answer is the answer to your own question, then why did you accept the other answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).